# Trying to create bin using WOE package for multiple column in r using for loop, how can i use column name in for loop to create multiple results

Tags: r

I'm trying to create bin using WOE package for multiple column in r using for loop, how can I use column name in for loop to create multiple results?

```
library(woe)
Summary_WOE <- data.fram()
for ( i in names(DF))
{ Summary)WOE <- woe(Data= DF,DF[[i]],TRUE,"target",10,Bad=0, Good=1)}
```

Trying to get the summary for each column from df and save it in Summary_WOE.